# Como cambio de status ocupando redux en react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Necesitó cambiar una variable, pero esta variable en el store esta asi le comparto la data

```
Data
export const lists =[  
   {
   "id":1,
  "listname":"2022-09-09 00:00:00",
  "products":[
     {
        "id":1,
        "idlist":1,
        "product":"leche",
        "quantity":1,
        "measure":"litro",
        "status":false
     },
     {
        "id":2,
        "idlist":1,
        "product":"pan",
        "quantity":1,
        "measure":"Kg",
        "status":false
     },
 ]},
]
```

el dato que quiero cambiar es status

se me ocurrió esta idea en el reduce, en el action esta definido la action

```
case CHANGE_PRODUCT_STATUS:
      const newList = state.lists.products.findIndex(
        (product) => product.id === action.productId
      );      
      if (newList === -1) return state;
      return {
        ...state,
        lists: state.lists.products[newList].status = !state.lists.products[newList].status,
      };
```

me da un error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.lists.proucts.findIndex')

COmo lo puedo solucionar gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo el ejemplo de como tienes el estado state.lists es un array y no puedes realizar esto state.lists.products.findIndex, primero tendrías que buscar el index de la lista y de ahi realizar la búsqueda del producto y actualizar el estatus ejemplo:

```
case CHANGE_PRODUCT_STATUS:
  const listUpdated = [...state.list];
  const listaIndex = state.list.findIndex(item => item.id === action.listId);
  const newList = state.lists[listaIndex].products.findIndex(
    (product) => product.id === action.productId
  );      
  if (newList === -1) return state;

  listUpdated[listaIndex].products[newList].status = listUpdated[listaIndex].products[newList].status;
  return {
    ...state,
    lists: [... listUpdated],
  };
```